# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ase.mep'

Tags: atomic-simulation-environment

I am trying to find the transition path using NEB method in ASE. However when i try to import the ase.mep module, i am getting the following error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ase.mep''

Can anyone explain me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue.

I had to use it like this:

from ase.neb import NEB

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a disconnect between the ASE documentation online and the release version of ASE (2 years old).  If you want to view the correct documentation, you can render out the documentation locally using Sphinx.